# Need help regarding Android app design

Tags: android, user-interface

I am new to Android development. I am developing an app having many heterogeneous screens. I want to show help for each screen which will describe purpose of that screen. What would be the best way to do it? Currently I am showing a help popup as I visit a each screen. I have given a checkbox on help popup named "Don't show again". Still I am not happy with it since it seems too distracting to me. Any ideas how can I achieve it?

Comment: What do you mean by "distracting"?
You can set a flag inside your `SharedPreferences` (or any other data storage). If it is the first time the user opens that `Activity` show the Popup, otherwise don't.

Comment: Please see if it is what you need
[showcase-view](http://www.androidviews.net/2012/11/showcase-view/).

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use a ShowCaseView to help your consummer at the first launch of each activity.

[ShowCaseView Github project](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView)